# Centralizer of a reductive subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$ and $H\subseteq G$ a reductive subgroup. Let $\rho$ be a faithful irreducible finite dimensional representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $\rho|_H$ is reducible. Then is it always the case that the centralizer $Z_G(H)$ is strictly larger than the center $Z(G)$?

Comment: Probably it would have been fine to edit [your original question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436947/), where after a counterexample you now replaced the assumption that $H$ is a proper subgroup, with the assumption that $G$ is irreducible but not $H$ (in the original form $G$ was $\mathrm{SO}_n$ acting on $\mathbf{C}^n$ and the counterexample was the image of an odd-dimensional rep of $\mathrm{SL}_2$).

Comment: And then a variation works here. Take dimension 4, $G=\mathrm{SO}_4$, and $H$ the image of the 3-dim irreducible of $\mathrm{SL}_2$ (i.e., $H$ is the upper left $\mathrm{SO}_3$). The centralizer of $H$ in $\mathrm{GL}_4$ consists of those diagonal$(a,a,a,b)$ matrices, and hence in $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ it consists of $\{\pm 1\}$, and this is precisely the center of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$.

Comment: @Windi: Hmm... 24 questions but only 1 accepted answer? You must be very difficult to please.

Comment: Can't you just take $G$ any reductive group, $H$ any proper reductive subgroup with $C_G(H)=Z(G)$, and then take $\rho$ to be the representation on the Lie algebra of $G$?

Comment: @Windi as Alex M. suggests, you should accept answers of questions whenever the answers are correct. Accepting correct answers is useful to everybody in this site and shows consideration to people who're trying to help you. Please take this into account.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, why should [your](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436952/centralizer-of-a-reductive-subgroup/436953#comment1126068_436952) $\rho$ be irreducible on $H$? (A basic example: it isn't if $Z(G)$ has positive dimension.)

Comment: @LSpice It won't usually. I should have taken $G$ to be simple: if $H<G$ then $L(H)$ is always a submodule of $L(G)$. The question asked for the restriction to be reducible though, not irreducible. I just chose the Lie algebra because proper subgroups are *guaranteed* to yield reducible restrictions.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, oops, I misread!

Comment: @YCor: Thanks for letting me know about it. To be perfectly honest, I simply didn't know there is such thing as "accepting anwsers". I just took care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$No. Take $H=\GL_2$ embedded diagonally into $G=\GL_2\times \GL_2$ and take
$\rho$ equal to $\mathbb C^2 \otimes (\mathbb C^2)^*$ with the natural action of $\GL_2$ on $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: I think you mean "take $\rho$ to be the natural action of $G = \operatorname{GL}_2 \times \operatorname{GL}_2$ on $\mathbb C^2 \otimes (\mathbb C^2)^*$" (which then specifies how $H = \operatorname{GL}_2$ acts).  To think about it another way, $\rho$ is the action of $G$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(H)$ by simultaneous left and right multiplication $(h_1, h_2)\cdot X = h_1 X h_2^{-1}$, and the restriction to $H$ is then the adjoint action, which is reducible.

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean.